# Nodejs to ES6: Requested node modules do not provide an export

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, import, socket.io, package

I'm new to node.js, and I'm trying to import node_modules packages ('express', 'http' and 'socket.io') into a project written in ES6 Module.

Traditional method like `require(express)` does not work for me, as the project is written in ES6 Module instead of Node.js.

Online resources suggest using 'import' to replace 'require()':

```
import express from 'express'
import socket.io from 'socket.io'
```

However, I need to use a path from the installed package instead, like this:

```
import {express} from "../../../node_modules/express/index.js";
```

but it throws error, as express 'does not provide an export named default'.

I cannot find one file that includes default `export`, as most of the node-packages uses `module.exports`

Here's my codes:

index.js:

```
import express from "express";
import { Server } from "../../../node_modules/socket.io";

const app = express();

let port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
let server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Listening on PORT :' + port);
});
const io = Server(server);
```

package.json:

```
{
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "socket.io": "^4.5.4"
  },
,
  "name": "package.json",
  "type": "module",
}
```

How can I import node-modules to my project?

Comment: If you have `"type": "module"` in `package.json` and you've done `npm install express`, then `import express from "express";` works just fine.  Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, including the steps you took to bootstrap the project. In my case, I double-checked by doing `npm init -y && npm install express`, editing `package.json` to add `"type": "module"`, and using this `index.js`: `import express from "express"; console.log(typeof express);` It output the string "function" as expected.

Comment: I followed your steps but found the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "express". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"."

Comment: There must be a problem with your Node / npm installation then. Those steps definitely work in a clean directory with a non-corrupted installation.